# Google Calendar API: how to disable all reminders?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API to CRUD events in my web application.

I want to overwrite the default reminders settings with the value `don't send any reminders`.

All I found was to [overwrite the default](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.useDefault), but with a new value (`email 10 minutes` for example).

So is there a way to set the reminder to `false` via the Google Calendar API?

This how the JSON looks like:

```
"reminders": {
   "useDefault": boolean,
   "overrides": [
     {
       "method": string,
       "minutes": integer
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.overrides

The entry for the `reminders.overrides[]` object says:

> "If the event doesn't use the default reminders, this lists the
>   reminders specific to the event, or, **if not set, indicates that no
>   reminders are set for this event.**"

(my emphasis).

Therefore I think you can just set

```
"useDefault": false
```

and don't supply any overrides, and it should result in the event having no reminders.