# How to remove event notification using Google Calendar API v3 (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, google-calendar-api

I have the following JSON

```
var resource = {
  "summary": "Sample Event",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": sample1
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": twoHoursLater
  },
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "method": "popup",
        "minutes": "5"
      },
      {
        "method": "email",
        "minutes": "5"
      }

    ]
  }
};
```

I can insert it to Google Calendar using the code below

```
function addEvent() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      'calendarId':   calendarId,
      'resource':     resource
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
}
```

In Google Calendar website it appears as:

```
5 minutes before, as email
5 minutes before
```

As you can see the event the I have has reminders, meaning it will notify via Popup and Email, 5 minutes before the event starts.

Now, the thing is I want to remove this event reminder programatically using the API.

**What I have tried so far:**

**Test 1:**

Based on the documentation https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders

It says "To revert back to the default set of reminders, perform an update setting `reminders.useDefault` back to `true.`"

```
var resource3 = {
  "summary": "Sample Event xx",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": sample1
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": twoHoursLater
  },
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
  }
};

function updateEvent(eventId) {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
      'calendarId':   calendarId,
      'eventId':     eventId,
      'resource':     resource3
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
}
```

The code above will return an error `Cannot specify both default reminders and overrides at the same time.` in the console.

**Test 2:**

Based on an accepted answer on stackoverflow [Google Calendar API: How to disable Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805735/google-calendar-api-how-to-disable-notifications)

It says "Therefore I think you can just set `"useDefault": false`
and don't supply any overrides, and it should result in the event having no reminders."

```
var resource3 = {
  "summary": "Sample Event xx",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": sample1
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": twoHoursLater
  },
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false
  }
};

function updateEvent(eventId) {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
      'calendarId':   calendarId,
      'eventId':     eventId,
      'resource':     resource3
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
}
```

The patching/updating works on other fields such as `summary`, `start`, and `end`. But it does not remove the event reminder.

**Test 3:**

This is what I have experimented on so far. I removed the reminders completely. Still no luck. Same output as in Test 2.

```
var resource3 = {
  "summary": "Sample Event xx",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": sample1
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": twoHoursLater
  }
};

unction updateEvent(eventId) {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
      'calendarId':   calendarId,
      'eventId':     eventId,
      'resource':     resource3
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to remove the event reminder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after working around with it, I successfully removed the event notification using the API. The answer is almost close as stated in **Test 2** and it is done by using the code below:

```
var resource3 = {
  "summary": "Sample Event xx",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": sample1
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": twoHoursLater
  },
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false,
    "overrides": []
  }
};

function updateEvent(eventId) {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
      'calendarId':   calendarId,
      'eventId':     eventId,
      'resource':     resource3
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
}
```

I just need to add the `overrides` and giving it an empty value. I hope this helps if you encountered the same question.

Answer (score 0):

When patching using the libraries you can't just set overrides to null, you need to use Data.nullOf(ArrayList.class):

```
 Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                        .setUseDefault(false)
                        .setOverrides(Data.nullOf(ArrayList.class));
                newEvent.setReminders(reminders);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `patch`/`update` for the event following the

```
reminders: {
  useDefault: false,
  overrides: []
}
```

only worked for Firefox, while Chrome kept stubbornly holding onto the defaults. (It was super baffling, I checked it several times: the same event would have different reminders when viewing it in Firefox vs Chrome.)

The way I got around it was by not *creating* the events in the first place, using the Calendar API:

```
const event = {
  start: {...},
  end: {...},
  summary: 'My Event',
  reminders: {
    useDefault: false
  }
}
Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId)
```

This means I couldn't use the (slightly easier) [Calendar service provided by Google in the app scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar) but hey the API isn't too bad either.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var resource3 = {
  "summary": "Sample Event xx",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": sample1
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": twoHoursLater
  },
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false,
    "overrides": []
  }
};

function updateEvent(eventId) {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
      'calendarId':   calendarId,
      'eventId':     eventId,
      'resource':     resource3
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
}
```